# Using a PendingIntent to toggle airplane mode

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, airplane-mode

I am working on an app for Android, for which I would like to be able to toggle Airplane Mode using a PendingIntent. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.cancel(pi);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 20000, 20000, pi);
```